# VSTS REST API for creating TFVC Branch

Tags: rest, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to automate some of my build related tasks, which includes creating new release branch and build definitions for each release. I use *VSTS TFVC* for version management. When i am trying to do it with TFS REST API, i couldn't find any API for creating branch ([microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/branches?view=vsts-rest-4.1)).

I can see [.NET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb141847%28v%3Dvs.120%29) available to do this; unable to find one as REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such a REST API to create branch for now, I have submitted a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/35019529-add-vsts-tfs-rest-api-for-creating-branch) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.

As a workaround you can try below ways to create a branch in code or script:

- Just as @Shayki mentioned you can use [Client Object Model Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx#clientapireference)
   if you want to manage the Version Control programmatically. 
  Just use the "`CreateBranch()`" method in
  [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.aspx)
  class to create a branch.
- Besides, you can also use the [Branch Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/repos/tfvc/branch-command?view=vsts) to create a branch.

---

```
tf branch olditem newitem [/version:versionspec] [/noget] [/lock:(none|checkin|checkout)] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/checkin] [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)] [/author:authorname] [/login:username, [password]] [/recursive]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as what you see in "Branches" page, there isn't any way to create branch with the Rest API. And mostly, you can only read/get the information with the Version Control API for now.

If you don't want use C#, you can automate the process with Powerhshell:

```
param(

)
begin
{
 # load the required dll's
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client")   
}

process
{
 $server = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServer("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection")

 $vcServer = $server.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer]); 

 $changesetId = $vcServer.CreateBranch('$/Demo/Code/Main', '$/Demo/Code/Dev/Branch', [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec]::Latest, $null, "New branch from script", $null, $null, $null)

 "Branch created with ChangesetID: $changesetId"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. Yeah, i am aware of this, and i am trying to automate it using Python script. I was wondering why microsoft didn't support this.